# Return substring of all lines that start with [+] between two specific lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a sample multi-line string that looks like this:

```
[+] x: somerandomstuff
[!] blah
[+] x: somemorerandomstuff
[-] blah
[+] START
[+] x: 1st group to match
[!] blah
[-] blah
[+] x: 2nd group to match
[+] END
```

I want to match the strings after the `x:` in lines that look like `[+] x: (...)`, but *only* those that are between `[+] START` and `[+] END`. The expected result would be two groups (there could be more):

```
1st group to match
2nd group to match
```

Note that there will only be one instance of START/END.

I've only managed to come up with something that matches the first group:

```
\[\+\] START.*?\[\+\] x: (.*?)\n.*\[\+\] END
```

I currently lack the knowledge to extend this regex to match the other lines. I'm not sure how to look for multiple lines that match a pattern, between another pattern (`[+] START` and `[+] END`)

**REGEX101 Link: https://regex101.com/r/kCgwhr/2**

*note: I know that a regex-only solution may not be the best thing here, but I would like to solve this with only regex.*

Comment: This is not possible with a single regex. You can't match arbitrarily many noncontiguous substrings.

Comment: If not necessarily to match `START` could [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for an `END` with no `START` until next `END`: [`\[\+\] x: (.*+)$(?=(?>\n(?!\[\+\] START).*)*\n\[\+\] END)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/yRd7vH/3)

Comment: @Juicy In Python you can [try this variant](https://www.regex101.com/r/yRd7vH/4) which has less magic (use with `re.MULTILINE`). For answer regex with `\G` to work you probably need  the [alternative regular expression module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). It's always good to specify regex flavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you use a PCRE compatible regex, as you are using regex101 in PCRE mode.

You can make use of the \G continuous matching (and some lookahead stuff) to match what you want:

```
(?:\[\+\] START|\G(?!\A))\R(?:(?!\[\+\] x:)(?!\[\+\] END).*\R)*\[\+\] x:\s*\K.*
```

This matches:

- `(?:\[\+\] START|\G(?!\A))` - the start sequence or right after the previous match. `\G` matches at the start of the string the first time the regex is called, so `(?!\A)` ensures that `\G` is only used after the first match is found.
- `\R` - any newline sequence
- `(?:(?!\[\+\] x:)(?!\[\+\] END).*\R)*` - any amount of lines that neither start with the end sequence or the sequence we want to match (basically to skip over them)
- `\[\+\] x:\s*` - starts the sequence we want to match
- `\K` - omits everything matched before (so we only match what we really want)
- `.*` the content of our wanted line

See it working in [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/WxaTFI/1).

Comment: Nice (if a bit crazy), but this needs a loop around the regex to make it multiple times. Depending on the programming language or tool you're using, this may require a `while` loop or special matching function.

Comment: @melpomene yep, but luckily most languages or tools should have some kind of match all functionality. It might be possible to do in a single pass with engines that support access to groups that were matched multiple times (.net, PyPi regex), but one had to loop over the content afterwards.